# How to count rows month wise

Tags: mysql, date, count, rows

With this query i can count

```
Created By  ProductGroup           Count
HNSHAK      MOBILE COMPUTING        13
HNSHAK      STORAGE                 2
```

Query:

```
SELECT `Created By`, ProductGroup, COUNT(*) `Count`
FROM tablename
GROUP BY `Created By`, ProductGroup;
```

now i want to count same month wise like MARCH/APRIL or 04-2013/03-2013 kindly help if it is possible i have a database in which more than 15000 entries i want to show each user count month wise...

i want output like this

```
Created By  ProductGroup           Count    MONTH
HNSHAK      MOBILE COMPUTING        1       MARCH
HNSHAK      STORAGE                 2       MARCH


Created By  ProductGroup           Count    MONTH
HNSHAK      MOBILE COMPUTING        2       APRIL
HNSHAK      STORAGE                 1       APRIL

Created By  ProductGroup           Count    MONTH
HNSHAK      MOBILE COMPUTING        1       FEBRUARY
```

table:

```
Productgroup    Created By  Initial Intl Created
STORAGE             HNSHAK  13.02.2013
SMART+MOBIL+FIX PH. KFKAIS  19.03.2013
SMART+MOBIL+FIX PH. KFKAIS  20.03.2013
SMART+MOBIL+FIX PH. KFKAIS  19.03.2013
SCANNERS            MDSALA  20.02.2013
STORAGE             HNSHAK  07.03.2013
STORAGE             HNSHAK  13.03.2013
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK  01.03.2013
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK  01.04.2013
MOBILE COMPUTING    HNSHAK  01.04.2013
PTV/FLAT            WSAHMA  12.03.2013
PTV/FLAT            WSAHMA  09.03.2013
STORAGE             HNSHAK  13.03.2013
```

Comment: What you're looking for if I've understood you correctly is what you want to do is group by month

try this 

`SELECT `Created By`, ProductGroup, COUNT(*) `Count`
FROM tablename
GROUP BY `Created By`, ProductGroup, MONTH('Initial');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[MonthName](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)**

```
select [created by],
       ProductGroup,
       Count(Productgroup),
       MonthName([Initial Intl Created])
from tablename
group by [created by],ProductGroup,MonthName([Initial Intl Created])
```

Comment: Mine was exactly the same other then I used MONTH() instead which works perfecyly fine and you dont have to asign it in the select...

but oh well

Comment: @Luv can you tell me how to display year with month like MARCH 2013 this code works perfect for month wise count i need to display year too with month

Comment: Yes.. **Add Where clause.** `where MonthName([Initial Intl Created])='MARCH' AND where YEAR([Initial Intl Created])='2013'`. **[Year](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)**

Comment: @Luv no dear i don't want to put year my self because if next year come i.e 2014 than i have to change query i want to take year from Initial Intl Created.

Comment: `where MonthName([Initial Intl Created])='MARCH' AND where YEAR([Initial Intl Created])=YEAR(CURDATE())`. Now you don't have to put **Year** Manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CreatedBy, Productgroup, COUNT(*) AS Count, DATE_FORMAT(CreateDate, '%Y-%m') AS Period
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY CreatedBy, Productgroup, Period ;
```

You just need to add Month / Period group.

Sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/3f435/1